# Meaning of "firm decision"

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

Could anyone explain to me what is the meaning of the phrase below?

> **"firm decision"**

I searched for it in Google but found no answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A

> firm decision

is a decision which will not easily be changed or reversed, it is "firm".